# Gigya - Single Sign-On

Tags: gigya

Our company has been using this Gigya. One of the implementations we did was an SSO for our group sites that registered to Gigya Site settings. However we got some issues regarding with auto login and auto log out from relative sites that in the same group.

For instance, siteA and siteB are in the same SSO group. However when you logout from siteA, when you refresh siteB, nothing happens which we should expect to automatically logout. The work around we did was to detect the current session of gigya in the browser then if the user's active already expired/deleted, we will trigger our code to logout.

We thought this feature for auto login and auto logout should handle by Gigya scripts? By the way we are using Gigya RaaS premium package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the "Logout URL" to siteB?

Look in Gigya [documentation](http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/10_UM360/060_Single_Signon) in the Single Sign-On, User logout section.

> Make sure to complete the following steps to enable a successful SSO
>   logout:
>
> 1.Every member site should have a logout URL. This is a page that contains the Gigya script and issues a call to accounts.logout /
>   socialize.logout accordingly, effectively logging out the active user
>   when the page is loaded.
>
> 2.Send a complete list of logout URLs to your implementation manager. Make sure to have a logout URL for every site.
>
> 3.Make sure to implement user log out with a call to accounts.logout / socialize.logout to notify Gigya.

Comment: Yes we gave sets of Logout URL to our Contact in Gigya Team for all sites we have. Anyway thanks for the information and tips. I'll take a look at it! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

the logout URL is not implemented for SSO group AFAIK.
and gigya cannot delete the session of your sites ( only call an URL). unless you can yourself chain the logout urls via parameters, it is not feasable. What you are doing ( verifying the gigya session status and calling your own logout ) is the way to go.